# how to make a form readable to a user and editable to another user

Tags: php, laravel-5

The code below grants only the `admin` and `user_a` to see the form. But I want to make a section of the form readable to only `user_a`.

```
@if(Auth::user()-> user_role == "admin" || Auth::user()-> user_role == "user_a")   
//form   
@endif
```

Comment: Why not just add another `if(Auth::user()->user_role == "user_a")`? Or what exactly is your question?

Comment: You don't need to write different code just add readonly in your html content when you want to display your content not to edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@if(Auth::user()-> user_role == "admin" || Auth::user()-> user_role == "user_a")   
    //form


   // specific section
   @if(Auth::user()-> user_role == "user_a")
   // This section is visible to the role user_a only
   @endif

@endif
```

Comment: thanks works now.. in the input tag i added the second If statement. and within the if statement *readonly